# Analysis of variance vs. homoscedasticity assumption

Tags: anova, linear-model, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

If the assumption of homogeneity of variances is met,
how could the variances be different among groups in [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#The_F-test)
(the analysis dealing with between/within variability) ?

That is for me, ANOVA is something close to:
the ratio F = variance between groups / variance within groups.

So, if the (between/within) variances should be equal (according to the assumption),
F should be close to 1. Then what is the reason to have homoscedasticity assumption met before ANOVA (F test) calculation?

Comment: The question is unclear, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Who or what is "they"?

Comment: How do you know that the assumption is met ?  How do you know that the variances differ ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that the variances *within groups* are equal. There is no assumption about the variances between groups. This means that the ratio variance between groups/variance within groups can take any value under the assumption.

(Qualification: The null hypothesis assumes that the true variance between group means is zero, so under the null hypothesis you'd expect the F-statistic to be not very large, but under the alternative it can become arbitrarily large, and in any case the equal variances within groups assumption alone doesn't constrain it in any way.)

Comment: Then what is the reason to have homoscedasticity assumption met before ANOVA (F test) calculation?

Comment: Carl, I guess Christian Hennig was clear, no? Oh, I did not get what you mean... Could you please, elaborate?

Comment: @Carl The homoscedasticity assumption is required for the theoretical computation of the (F-)distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis.

Comment: @abc The context requiring homoscedasticity was less clear than the question and answer themselves. For example, the F-distribution is the ratio of two df normalized Chi-squared distributions, where each Chi-squared distribution is by assumption the sum of df normal distributions. How this relates to homoscedasticity is not as yet obvious to me.